# Asynchronous Procedure Call interrupted by another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, apc

I just realized that my APC is interrupted by another thread.
So at this point I wonder how this could be.
As I understood the concept of APCs:

- an APC can not be interrupted by a normal user-mode thread
- an APC is dispatched as soon as its requested by QueueUserAPC()
- an APC has run-to-completion semantics

So this is my initial situation:
I have a multi-threaded application (1 main thread, 1 reception thread). 
The reception thread of lower priority is receiving data from an external source.
The reception thread is also reactivated by using `WaitForSingleObject()`.
Received data is stored in a shared `std::list`.
The main thread does effectively nothing.
Every x milliseconds a special event occurs that causes the reception thread to dispatch an APC.
This APC is running in the context of the main thread.

So here is an example pseudo source code of the whole situation.

```
class Example {

public:
  Example(void) {
    ::DuplicatHandle(
        ::GetCurrentProcess(),
        ::GetCurrentThread(),
        ::GetCurrentProcess(),
        &m_mainthreadHandle,
        THREAD_SET_CONTEXT,
        FALSE,
        0);
  }

  void run(void) {
    ::WaitForSingleObjectEx(m_apcActivation);
  }

protected:

private:
  void rxThread(void) {
    // this seems to be called during the apcRoutine() is running
    // as result the shared list m_rxList is corrupted!
    ::WaitForSingleObject(m_externalActivation);

    Data data = externalReceive();

    if(data.attribute == SPECIAL) {
      ::QueueUserAPC(apcRoutine, m_mainthreadHandle, 0);
    } else {
      m_rxList.push_front(data);
    }
  }

  void apcRoutine(void) {
    while(!m_rxList.empty()) {
      m_rxList.front().print();
      m_rxList.pop_front();
    }
  }


  std::list<Data> m_rxList;
  HANDLE          m_externalActivation;
  HANDLE          m_apcActivation;
  HANDLE          m_mainthreadHandle;

};


void main(void) {

  Example e;

  e.run();

}
```

My question is:
Is it possible that `WaitForSingleObject()` of the reception thread interrupts the APC?
If yes, why?

Answer (score 6):

You seem to have a few misconceptions about APCs.

There are two (actually three) kinds of APCs, usermode and kernelmode (with two different priorities) APCs.

Usermode APCs such as the ones you use in your code do not behave the same way kernelmode APCs do. In particular:

- They do not preempt the thread,
- They do not run immediately when you call `QueueUserAPC` except if the target thread is already blocked in an alertable wait. Instead, APCs are *queued*.
- They are otherwise only run when the thread enters an alertable wait or when `NtTestAlert` is called.
- They are not un-preemptable, in fact there is nothing inherently "special" about them. They're just callbacks that you can queue to a thread and which are called at well-defined times.
- They do not guarantee run-to-completion<sup>1</sup>, but they guarantee in-order execution.
- There is no way to force another thread to execute its queued APCs. The target thread must make itself alertable for its APCs to run. Although there exists an undocumented function `NtAlertThread`, it does not work as one would expect, nor does `NtAlertResumeThread`.

Kernelmode APCs on the other hand do preempt usermode threads and are not interruptible by them (and APC_LEVEL APCs are not interruptible by PASSIVE_LEVEL APCs either).

---

<sup>1</sup> It would be pretty absurd if that was the case, too. That way, you could totally subvert the scheduler using an APC, consuming an undeterministic amount of CPU time -- regardless of process priorities, privilegues, or quotas.